# What kind of a flower is this?

Tags: identification

It started out with large green leafs with cream colored spots. Then it got a flower leaf like a calla Lilly with a cream stem. Now the leaves & flower have dried up and there is this cream colored stalk about 1” in diameter with orange bead like seed pods on the to half of the stem

Comment: Please post a picture.

Comment: I tried to send you a picture but it was to big and  wouldn’t upload

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE! This is an identification question and I recommend you read the [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). And as for all new users, the [tour] and [help] will get you started quickly.

Comment: I just resized (and then uploaded) a picture with Preview on macOS. What platform are you using? Resizing pictures is not difficult.

Comment: Hi Cnoland 71, I see that you're still with us, which is great! Do you still need help loading pictures? Our system is picky and resizing can indeed be difficult. I've been here for years and it still is for me! What photo program are you using? Also, have you looked at any of the plants in user22542's answer? Do any look like yours? If so, let us know which one and we can edit your question. Your description is already great, so we thank you for that!

Comment: f we don't have enough information to get you a good answer, we may put the question on-hold for a few days to give you a chance to [edit] it. The explanation of that process is on [this page](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) of our [help]. We're still looking forward to helping you. I'm sure other people would like to know more about your plant.

Answer (score 1):

From your description as "**similar to a calla lily**" with resulting **orange "berries"** on the top half of the stem, it does sound like your plant could be from either the genera "**Zantedeschia**" or **"Arum"**. These are genus members of the Arum family "Araceae". The plant genus "**Zantedeschia**" is commonly referred to as "calla lilies". It might possibly be **Zantedeschia albomaculata** which has white spotted leaves, but without a photo it is not possible determine the exact species or cultivar you may have.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zantedeschia

https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/37982/

http://worldhouseplants.com/arum-italicum-seed-pod/